# undefined method `stringify_keys!' for "test":String meta_search Multiple search in one action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search, meta-search

I am trying to use meta_search to run search on multiple models in the same controller. With my current code if I input something for the Database it works but when I try Application I get the following error

```
 NoMethodError in HomeController#index

undefined method `stringify_keys!' for "test":String

app/controllers/home_controller.rb:6:in `index'

Parameters: 
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"MFFR9GHZWSPBBFugTSvr7ZMJlxpWwGZqeNH3/SzPQ8k=",
 "q"=>"",
 "apps_name"=>"test",
 "commit"=>"Search"}
```

home_controller.rb

```
    class HomeController < ApplicationController
        def index
           @search = Database.search(params[:q])
           @databases = @search

           @search2 = Application.search(params[:apps_name])
           @application_s = @search2 
       end

       def about
       end    
  end
```

index.html.erb

```
<%= form_tag("/home/index", :method => "get") do %>
  <%= label_tag(:q, "Database:") %>
  <%= text_field_tag(:q) %>
  <%= submit_tag("Search") %>
<% end %>

<%= form_tag("/home/index", :method => "get") do %>
  <%= label_tag(:app_name, "Application:") %>
  <%= text_field_tag(:app_name) %>
  <%= submit_tag("Search") %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: the trace states that the error is in line 9 of the controller, under the index action.  But manually counting the number of lines led me to believe that you removed some code inside the action.  If you did remove any code, can you update the question with your complete index action?

Comment: What arguments do the "search" methods you call accept? Seems like they expect hashes and instead of that, you pass strings.

Comment: jvnill--> I have updated my controller.
grotori --> I am new to rails but I believe the search function from meta_search accepts array of string as argument.